# JBPM drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.error

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jbpm, bpmn

I started working on JBPM 5.4 and currently trying to run the examples provided by the community. While running them I always get this error.

**drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.error  - (null: 12, 54): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'targetNamespace' must appear on element 'definitions'.**

Please help me understand how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The XML parser is expecting the targetNamespace to be set on the definitions tag, so you should simply add that:

Kris